# Sysdate function in SQL Insert query

Tags: mysql, sql, sysdate, insert-statement

I am writing code in jsp. I am running  following query, which runs well but place a **`NULL`** in **`entryDate`**-column in DB.

```
int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into mtc (entryDate) values sysdate()");
```

What is mistake in this query?

I have to store current system date in `entryDate`-column.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Oracle?

Comment: I don't know much about the jsp side but I believe you may need parenthesis around your sysdate field so something like:             int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into mtc (entryDate) values (SYSDATE())");

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson its Mysql (sqlyog)

Comment: @EM923 Then sjramsay's comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into mtc (entryDate) values (SYSDATE())");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try writing the mysql function in uppercase :

```
int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into mtc (entryDate) values SYSDATE()");
```

Comment: Oops, sjramsay was right, don't forget to put the value in parenthisis ^^ My apologies.
`int j=st.executeUpdate("insert into mtc (entryDate) values (SYSDATE())");`